# A question about the roots of a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Question; If one root of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is treble the other prove that
$3b^2 - 16ac = 0$

My attempt:
 we know that  $\alpha + \beta = -\frac{b}{a}$

$\alpha \beta = \frac{c}{a}$

let one root be x and treble x to be 3x

sum of it is 4x and the product is $3x^2$

im  stuck from here
please can some one help me

thank you

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but what does treble mean...?

Comment: @SimpleArt Adjectival meaning #1 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/treble?s=t) ?

Comment: @SimpleArt It is a variant spelling of “triple”.

Comment: Don't mind me, treble just sounds weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Towers’ solution may be a little quicker, but there is more than one way to solve a problem, and you should not think that what you were doing was wrong.  Your idea was good, and I think it is important for you to see that  if you had been able to push on a little farther you could have gotten the answer.

Continuing from where you left off: You said $\alpha + \beta = -\frac ba$ and $\alpha\beta = \frac ca$, which is correct.  You also said “Let one root be $x$ and treble $x$ to be $3x$”, which is fine; we can take $\alpha = x$ and $\beta = 3x$.  Then you have:  $$\begin{align}4x & = -\frac ba \\ 3x^2 & = \frac ca.\end{align}$$

Now we will calculate the value of $3b^2-16ac$ directly and see what we get.
First we calculate $3b^2$.  The first equation is all we have to work with, since it is the only one that includes $b$.  So take the first equation and square it, obtaining $16x^2 = \frac{b^2}{a^2}$, and then multiply both sides by $3a^2$, obtaining $$48a^2x^2= \color{darkblue}{3b^2}.\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

Now let's calculate $16ac$.  Take the second equation and multiply both sides by $16a^2$, obtaining $$48a^2x^2 = \color{darkred}{16ac}.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$

From $\spadesuit$ and $\clubsuit$ we have $$\color{darkblue}{3b^2} - \color{darkred}{16ac} = 48a^2x^2 - 48a^2x^2 = 0$$ and we win.

Comment: I personally would have left out $x$, and just said $\beta = 3\alpha$, but I think one of the best things about mathematics is that there are many different ways to get the right answer, and not everyone has to do things exactly the same way.

Comment: thank you very much i cannot  vote +1 for your post but please note it is very appreciated

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Let $r$ and $3r$ be the given roots.  $a(x-r)(x-3r) = a x^2 -4 arx + 3ar^2$ is then the most general polynomial with roots $r$ and $3r$.  Comparing coefficients, we see $3b^2 - 16ac = 3(-4ar)^2 - 16(a)(3 ar^2) = 48 a^2 r^2 - 48 a^2 r^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are 
$$
x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
We know that x_2=3x_1. Thus we have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&=3\cdot \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}
This is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{b}{a}&=\dfrac{4\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}
Both side multiplying by $2a$ yields
\begin{align*}
2b&=4\sqrt{b^2-4ac}
\end{align*}
Squaring both sides yields
$$
4b^2=16b^2-64ac\Leftrightarrow 12b^2-64ac=0\Leftrightarrow 3b^2-16ac=0\qquad \blacksquare
$$

Comment: good  thank you but what does x_2 mean

Comment: The index 2 in $x_2$ describes the second root.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate $x$ from

$$ax^2+bx+c=9ax^2+3bx+c=0.$$

By a suitable combination, you get

$$6bx+8c=0,$$

then

$$9a\left(-\frac{4c}{3b}\right)^2+3b\left(-\frac{4c}{3b}\right)+c=0.$$